# Where is "Applications and Services Logs" on Win2k3 when using ETWTrackingParticipant for WF?

Tags: workflow-foundation, windows-server-2003, workflow-foundation-4, event-log, etw

How do you view the ETW (*Event Tracing for Windows*) data when using `ETWTrackingParticipant` in WF 4 hosted on a Win2k3 server? For Windows 7 or Server 2k8, you can find it under **Event Viewer->Application and Services Logs->Microsoft->Windows->Application-Server Applications->Analytic**. Is there any way to see this tracking data running on a Windows 2003 Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ETW is available, but there is no UI to view the ETW logs unless you are on Windows Server 2008 or Windows Vista/7.

[Server Fault reference](https://serverfault.com/questions/327280/is-etw-available-in-windows-server-2003).